# Why is masonry not working in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/aderB

Masonry does not appear to be organizing divs in a grid layout.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').masonry({
   itemSelector: '.grid_4',
   isFitWidth: true,
   gutter: 8
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
   $('.container').masonry('reloadItems');
  });

new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( '#grid_4' ), {
        minDuration : 0.4,
        maxDuration : 0.7,
        viewportFactor : 0.2
      } );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not loading your masonry.js and imagesloaded.js because the links were not correct.

Here is a working example [codepen](http://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/eghEm)
 with some updated code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.container').imagesLoaded(function() {
  $('.container').masonry({
   itemSelector: '.grid_4',
   isFitWidth: true,
   gutter: 8
  });

  });

new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( '#grid_4' ), {
        minDuration : 0.4,
        maxDuration : 0.7,
        viewportFactor : 0.2
      } );

});
```

also, your AnimOnScroll uses an id of grid_4 yet you only have classes of grid_4 that I can see.